# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**I am kind of unsure about my solution to this problem and would love some feedback:**

$x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}$

What makes me unsure is the fact that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ and that $\ln(0)$ is undefined.

Just by looking at a graph, it looks like the answer should be zero.

I also come up with the following solution, but I am not quite sure about it (due to the fact that $\ln(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}))=Ø$ (not defined)

**The solution I've come up with so far goes like:**

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}$

$=-1\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}$ **Using the following rule to rewrite $a\cdot b=\frac{a}{\frac{1}{b}} b\neq0$**

$=-1\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}}}$

$-1\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{x^2}{\ln(\cos(x))}}$

**Using the chain rule for limits I found the following expression:**

$-1\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{x^2}{\ln(u)}}$

$\ln(u)=\ln(0)-\infty$ **(This is the part where I feel like I'm on thin ice)**

**Substituting back into the expression above:**

$-1\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{x^2}{-\infty}}$ (This is also a part where I suspect my notation is kind of bad.)

$-1\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{x^2}{-\infty}}\underset{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}{\rightarrow}0$

**So my questions are**

1. Is this a valid answer? **If not:** Is there someone who can provide me with a better solution (If possible with a step-by-step solution)?
2. If my notation is off anywhere, I would love some feedback. I'm a fresh student trying to learn as much as possible, so some productive feedback would be nice. (Please be nice and keep in mind that I am a fresh student just starting his calculus course)

If there are some out there who are kind enough to give me the feedback I'm hoping for, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Strong recommendation: Take $\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ out. Its limit is $4\pi^{-2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Ok, thanks! Would you mind showing me how you would do it in writing?

Comment: Make life easier starting with $x=\frac \pi 2-y$ and use the *strong recommendation*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Ok, sure I will. But does that mean that my solution is wrong? Or is it just a tip for a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use L'Hopital's rule, which states that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$, then $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}$$ if the limit is finite, $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. This also holds if instead $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$.

$$\begin{align}{\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}}&=-\frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot{\ln(\cos(x))}}{\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}x^2}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot{\ln(\cos(x))}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{\frac{1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)})}{(\frac{-1}{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2})}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(x)+(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2\cos(x)}{-\sin(x)}\\&=-\frac{4}{{\pi}^2}\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{0+0}{-1}\\&=0\end{align}$$Here L'Hopital's rule is used twice.

Feedback: Don't use $\infty$ when doing calculations, only when $\infty$ is the result of some limit, e.g. $$\lim_{x\to \infty}x=\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you for a complete, understandable, and well-explained answer!

Comment: @fredericoamigo, Why not use the tips from Claude Leibovici and Kavi Rama Murthy? It saves some work:

Substitue $x:=\frac{\pi}{2}-y$ and ignore $\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then
$$
-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\ln(\cos(x))=y \ln(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-y))=y\ln(\sin(y)).
$$
Now you can apply L'Hospital's rule to $y\ln(\sin(y))$ twice and see that $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}y\ln(\sin(y))=0$. In conjunction with $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ we get $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}-(x-\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{x^2}=0$

Comment: @Philipp: I agree that this is a compact and elegant way of solving the problem. The reason why I chose Austin's answer is that it is the one that resembles the methods I've learned in my calculus course so far. However, I really appreciate the solutions from Claude Leibovici, Kavi Rama Murthy, and yourself.  In my opinion, it is very valuable to compare solutions in order to be more flexible in your problem solving and therefore develop a deeper understanding. So in short: Thanks for a very well-thought-out and clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have written some gibberish of a kind that is common among students' attempts, which only means you need some more instruction: (1). Never put $\infty$ in an arithmetic expression with real numbers. There are no infinities in $\Bbb R$. The use of $\pm\infty$ in terms like $\lim_{r\to\infty}$ is an abbreviation, a "figure of speech". (2). If $A(x)\to 0$ and $B(x)\to 0$ as $x\to K,$ for example if $A(x)=x-\pi /2$ and $B(x)=x^2/\ln\cos x$ and $K=\pi/2,$ then $A(x)/B(x)$ might converge to $anything$ or fail to converge at all, as $x\to K$. You have to look into the properties of the particular $A(x)$ & $B(x).$

Assume $0<x<\pi /2$ so that $\cos x>0$ so that $\ln\cos x$ exists.

If $L=\lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} -(x-\pi /2) \ln\cos x$ exists then $\lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} -(x-\pi /2) \frac {\ln\cos x}{x^2}=L/(\pi/2)^2.$

Let $x=\pi/2 -y$. Then  $-(x-\pi /2) \ln\cos x=y\ln\sin y$ and $y\to 0^+$ as $x\to (\pi/2)^-.$

Now $\sin y =y(1+f(y))$ where $f(y)\to 0$ as $y\to 0$ because $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac {\sin y}{y}=1.$

So we have $y\ln\sin y=y\ln y +y\ln (1+f(y)).$

Now $\ln (1+f(y))\to 0$ as $y\to 0$ so the term $y\ln (1+f(y))\to 0$ too. This leaves the term $y\ln y,$which also $\to 0$ as $y\to 0^+,$ and there are many ways to show this.

Comment: Thanks for the useful feedback.  I'll definitely keep that in mind! Cheers.

Comment: What exactly is the function $f(y)$? Is it the tail of the Taylor series of $\sin(y)$ at point $0$?

Comment: @Philipp . $\sin y=y-y^3/3!+y^5/5!-...,$ so $f(y)=-y^2/3!+y^4/5!-...$ .